# SharePoint 2010 Workflow using Visual Studio books

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I recently started a project that requires me to create a very complex workflow in SharePoint 2010. I've read a couple of blogs, but they mostly cover the basics of creating workflows.

Are there any good books about creating SharePoint 2010 workflows in Visual Studio?

Comment: Workflows with Visual Studio are usually not well explained in the SHarePoint context. You should simply read up on Workflow Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no much for Workflows with Visual Studio, most of the material covers Designer, I had to go trough lots of Forums and Blogs to understand how to create them. however once you understand the basic logic the rest the usual Programming stuff for SharePoint.

to get started might recommend this book:

https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&pq=stackoverflow%20link%20to%20amazon&cp=51&gs_id=154&xhr=t&q=SharePoint%202010%20Development%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202010&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=SharePoint+2010+Development+with+Visual+Studio+2010&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1bf8971734a1165e&bpcl=38897761&biw=1366&bih=638

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ordered that book last week, so it should arrive shortly. It looks like a very good book